# Ruby ошибка ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)) когда по факту 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Использую Rails 6.1.3.1 и Ruby 3.0.1
В контроллере есть одна единственная строчка кода:

```
JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
```

И выдает ошибку. Понятия не имею откуда там 2 аргумента. Пробовал с самыми разными json, даже [] и {} просто.

Когда оставляю `JSON.parse()` то получаю `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)`

В чем проблема?

Comment: Странно, судя по спеке проблем не должно быть https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON (в версии 2.6 аналогично: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON)

Comment: @gil9red Вообще беда с JSON.  не работает pretty_generate с объектом params в контроллере. Выдает ошибку что должен быть json-объект либо массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагин HTTParty сломал очень много гемов (подозреваю что из-за своего json), не только JSON функции. Убрал и все заработало.
Ruby 3.0.1 on Rails 6.1.3.1